# 64bit version of the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DataStoreLoader assembly

Tags: .net, iis, deployment, tfs

I'm working on a very large website that uses functions from the 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DataStoreLoader' dll. Right now we ***really*** want to publish our web application in IIS as 64 bit only and leave the "Enable 32 bit applications" off.

This is the only assembly that I can't find a 64 bit version of. Does one exist that I can't find?

Are there any settings to change to avoid publishing this dll?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no 64bit version of the TFS client API.

As a 32 bit application on a 64 bit system runs faster in IIS than a native 64 I am not sire why you are requiring this.  unless you are using more than 2gb memory....

Answer (score 5):

I just find a 64bit version of this dll on "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_64\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DataStoreLoader\v4.0_12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\
" folder.

And there is another dll "Microsoft.WITDataStore.dll" in the same folder.

Copy both two DLLs to worker role, and it works; I think it should also work in web role.

Comment: You saved my day! I was facing a lot of issues while creating work items from Azure Worker Role as this DLL is 32 bit. It's pretty easy from Web Role as we can change IIS settings to allow 32 bit Apps. But from Worker Role, this is the proper (only?) solution as I can see.